How to handle payload on iOS device using FCM and APNS
I already built my chat app on android and it worked perfectly with data-only messages and notification message. the idea is to push notification when a message is sent to other users. if the app is in foreground, android will not show the notification but the onMessage handler will be called. if in background, the onBackgroundMessage handler will be called which sends the data to an isolate so that I can update the chat messages and show it when the user re-opens their device. everything worked just fine on android, on iOS though ...

notifications are always pushed even if app is in foreground (not really a problem).
no handler is being called if the app is in background or the user simply turned off their device but the app is still opened but still the notification is being sent. (THE REAL PROBLEM)

My main focus now is how to push data-only messages to iOS and handle them and push notifications conditionally.
I am using a library called kreait/firebase-php and this is there documentation on cloud messaging.
this is my code, I tried hard-coding it to easily debug and see if there is any problem with it:
public function sendDataMessage($deviceTokens, $data = [], $priority = "high")
    {
        $messaging = app('firebase.messaging');
        foreach ($deviceTokens as $token) {
            $payload = [
                "data" => [
                    "type" => "chat",
                    "action" => "receiveMessage",
                    "chat_id" => "3",
                    "message" => json_encode([
                        "id" => 24,
                        "content" => [
                            "type" => "Text",
                            "body" => "asdasd",
                            "size" => null
                        ],
                        "chat_id" => "3",
                        "sender" => [
                            "id" => 2,
                            "member_id" => 11,
                            "user_type" => 0,
                            "name" => "Owner",
                            "image" => "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=Owner&background=random&rounded=true&bold=true&uppercase=true"
                        ],
                        "is_admin" => false,
                        "seen" => [],
                        "status" => 1,
                        "seen_by_all" => false,
                        "deleted_at" => null,
                        "deleted" => false,
                        "created_at" => "2024-10-28T09:03:31.000000Z",
                        "updated_at" => "2024-10-28T09:03:31.000000Z"
                    ])
                ],
                // "notification" => [
                //     "title" => "New Message",
                //     "body" => "You have received a new message."
                // ],
                "apns" => [
                    "headers" => [
                        "apns-priority" => "10"
                    ],
                    "payload" => [
                        "aps" => [
                            "category" => "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY",
                            "content-available" => 1,
                            "mutable-content" => 1
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "token" => "d_XngYSzbUu2qpZyTw9YG3:APA91b......"
            ];

            try {
                $message = CloudMessage::fromArray($payload);
                // return $message->jsonSerialize();
                return $messaging->send($message);
            } catch (NotFound $e) {
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $e;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

worth noting that when uncommenting the notification object will push and handle notification with the payload perfectly but when commenting it, nothing happens, handlers are not even triggered!
